# VBA or Excel Formula to loop up multiple values with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, textjoin

Need help with
I've tried TEXTJOIN, INDEX/MATCH, CONCATENATE and don't seem to come to make it work.

This is what I'm trying to do

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(AND(TASKPRED!$B:$B=$A26,TASKPRED!$J:$J="Y",TASKPRED!$A:$A<>$C26),TASKPRED!$A:$A,""))
```

I have 2 sheets,
The current active sheet (which I'm working on)
and TASKPRED Sheet (which has all the tables and data I want to lookup)

I need whatever does the job, either formula or VBA,

If using a formula then these are the criterias

Criteria 1: Column B of TASKPRED must be equal to ActiveCell.value (which is $A26 in this example) that is in the current active sheet

Criteria 2: Column J of TASKPRED must be equal to "Y"

Criteria 3: Not already in column C of the current active sheet

I hope the above information makes sense

I appreciate your help

Comment: change `AND(TASKPRED!$B:$B=$A26,TASKPRED!$J:$J="Y",TASKPRED!$A:$A<>$C26)` to `(TASKPRED!$B:$B=$A26)*(TASKPRED!$J:$J="Y")*(TASKPRED!$A:$A<>$C26)`

Comment: Or the whole:`IF(AND(TASKPRED!$B:$B=$A26,TASKPRED!$J:$J="Y",TASKPRED!$A:$A<>$C26),TASKPRED!$A:$A,"")` to `FiLTER(TASKPRED!$A:$A,(TASKPRED!$B:$B=$A26)*(TASKPRED!$J:$J="Y")*(TASKPRED!$A:$A<>$C26),"")`

Comment: @ScottCraner This worked great thanks for your help! FiLTER(TASKPRED!$A:$A,(TASKPRED!$B:$B=$A26)*(TASKPRED!$J:$J="Y")*(TASKPRED!$A:$A<>$C26),"")